What does it mean if a sentence ends in て-form but it isn't a request
Full sentence: ジョギングをしてる時に足の筋を痛めちゃってさ。
The sentence ends with て but I don't understand what they want to achieve with that.

Relate or duplicate Deconstruction of "一緒できなくなっちゃって" / meaning of 歩けなくなっちゃって
